# Expected number of trials until N consecutive repetitions for any outcome out of a pair of outcomes.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, expected-value

Let's suppose I'm rolling a balanced dice with $m$ faces. Then any of the $m$ outcomes has equal probability $p$ to occur ($p=1/m$). I know that the formula for the expected number of trials until getting any of the outcomes repeated $N$ times in a row is $\frac{m^N-1}{m-1}$. I have seen the recursive derivation of this formula and I understand it.

But now, I'm having difficulties when trying to solve a slightly different problem. Let's suppose I'm rolling some kind of electronic dice where a pair of numbers $(x,y)$ is obtained with each roll. $x$ and $y$ can be any of $2m$ possible numbers, but $x\neq y$. I want to know the expected number of trials until getting $N$ times in a row a repeated single number. Not the exact pair but any of its numbers, regardless of position, repeated.

For example, if $m=6$, we have 12 possible outcomes for $x$ or $y$, let's say numbers 1 to 12. So, each roll will give two different numbers, for example (2,5). If in the next roll, we obtain (5,10), then number 5 was repeated regardless of being the first or the second output (let's say there is no order of the outputs, you just check if any of the numbers was repeated, and you count the trials until getting $N$ repetitions of any number).

The logic tells me that in this case (2 different outcomes out of $2m$ possibilities) the expected number of trials should be less than in the conventional case (1 outcome out of $m$ possibilities), since now there are two outputs with $1/m$ probability of repeating at the next trial and then I have twice the chances to see any of them repeating $N$ times. Actually, I did some simulation on Python and obtained roughly half the expected number of trials. I know it shouldn't be exactly half, since in that case, to keep increasing the size would make the expected number of trials converge to zero, and it should converge to $N$, not zero. But I was looking for some analytical derivation and couldn't get to any. Does anyone know how to obtain an analytical expression for the expected number of trials in this case?

Thank you

P.D. : My feeling is that this problem is not equivalent to throwing two dices with $m$ faces each one (although different numbers in each dice) at the same time, but it could be...

Comment: Just to clarify: on any "roll", any one of the $\ m(2m-1)\ $ pairs $\ \{i,j\}\ $ of integers, with $\ 1\le i<j\le 2m\ $, can appear, each with probability $\ \frac{1}{m(2m-1)}\ $. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thank you for the clarification.